# Dimension of differential equation - vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the dimension of this? and why? my guess is that it is 4 but I don't know how to show this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Write $p(x) = a_4 x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$.

What are $xp'(x), p''(x)$ in this form?

So now $p''(x) + xp'(x) + p = 0$ takes what form?

Use that $1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4 $ are lin. independent to conclude.